# Character Count Java Program gives java.lang.nosuchmethod

Tags: java

Can somebody explain why this code results in the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
```

```
class count_chars {

    int countit(String word, char ch) {
        int count = 0;
        int index = 0;
        while (index < word.length()) {
            if (word.charAt(index) == ch) {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            index = index + 1;
            return count;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public void main(String argv[]) {
        count_chars count = new count_chars();
        System.out.println("shit");
        System.out.println(countit("hello", 'o'));
    }
}
```

Comment: `public static void main(String argv[])`

Comment: count_chars -> CountChars

Comment: i didn't put in static cause it would say non-static method countit(java.lang.String,char) cannot be referenced from a static context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static int countit(String word, char ch) {
    int count = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while (index < word.length()) {
        if (word.charAt(index) == ch) {
            count = count + 1;
        }

        index = index + 1;
    }
    return count;
}

public static void main(String argv[]) {

    System.out.println("shit");
    System.out.println(countit("hello", 'e'));
}
```

Your main method must be static, or your program will not even start. Also if you declare your countit method static, too , you can access it from your main method, without creating a new object.

Also the logic in your countit is wrong, if it should count the appearence of a char in a string. In your version it will return 0 or 1 , because of the return inside your while loop (which could be replaced with a for loop , because you now the length of the string).

Answer (score 1):

First of all your main method should be static like:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
}
```

To correct your code:

```
public class CountChars {

    public int countit(String word, char ch) {
        int count = 0;
        int index = 0;
        while (index < word.length()) {
            if (word.charAt(index) == ch) {
               count = count + 1; 
            }
            index = index + 1;
            return count;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        CountChars count = new CountChars();
        System.out.println(count.countit("hello", 'o'));
    }
}
```

If you want to refference to a method within a class without instantiating an object of that class the method has to be static. So if you want to call your method countit() in you main method you should make that method static:

```
public static int countit(...){}
```